# Form post of array in sequence of post in php codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a form with 10 different input fields which appends in any order.

Example: attached Image[image: Form]

The code below to fetch data :

```
$news['paragraph'] = $this->input->post('paragraph');
$news['sub_heading'] = $this->input->post('sub_heading');       
$news['blurb'] = $this->input->post('blurb');       
$news['gallery_image'] = $this->input->post('gallery_image');       
$postdescription = $this->input->post('postdescription');
$news['pd_output'] = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $postdescription);   
$news['youtube_url'] = $this->input->post('youtube_url');       
$news['caption'] = $this->input->post('caption');       
$news['facebook'] = $this->input->post('facebook');
$news['twitter'] = $this->input->post('twitter');       
$news['instagram'] = $this->input->post('instagram');
$empty_data = array_filter($news);
$keys = array_keys($news_array);
    foreach($news_array as $key => $value){ 
        foreach($value as $val){
            $data_two = array( 
                'array_key'     => $key,
                'content'       => $val,
                'news_id'       => $this->input->post('object_id'),
                'created_on'    => date("Y-m-d"),
            );
            $this->db->insert('tbl_news_content',$data_two);
        }
    }
```

**Getting an array like** in foreach loop

```
[paragraph] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

[sub_heading] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )
```

i am getting keys and value from the array; but i want my data to be input as it was while adding the form.

paragraph
subheading
image
paragraph
paragraph
image

I have one table with 3 columns

id 
key_name 
content

Value of Key_name will be Key
Value of content will be value of key

Problem is the data gets inserted as

id     key_name     content
1      paragraph    1
2      paragraph    2
3      sub_heading  1
4      sub_heading  2

the data is not getting inserted as sequence mentioned while adding form.

Thanks

Comment: can you show your SQL statement?

Comment: or can you show us what you want the SQL querys to look like?

Comment: $keys = array_keys($news_array);
  foreach($news_array as $key => $value){ 
   foreach($value as $val){
    $data_two = array( 
     'array_key'  => $key,
     'content'   => $val,
     'news_id'   => $this->input->post('object_id'),
     'created_on'  => date("Y-m-d"),
    );
    $this->db->insert('tbl_news_content',$data_two);
   }
  }

Comment: I will update my post.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you trying to achieve, it assumes also that id column is INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT:

```
foreach ($news as $key => $value) {

    $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO your_table (key_name, content) 
        VALUES("%s", "%s")',
        $key, $value
    );
    //execute query in loop

}
```

Comment: Hi, Adding in Form as Paragraph Value 1, Sub Heading value 1, Paragraph value 2, Sub Heading value 2, But when it goes to database, Its adds as id 1 paragraph value 1, id 2, paragraph 2, id 3, sub heading 1, id 4, sub heading 2... Yes i am Using id as INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT

Comment: have you tried the approach in my answer? by executing query for each field?

Comment: No if you try it this way it should insert each $news array item as 1 query. Your $db class should have a method to insert a query like ->query($sql);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks sietse85 for looking in the code and taking the pain to answer my question. I have changed the input name of each field by appending with $x and before by adding "-" and with explode, removing the same before insert.

**Here is the code if it helps someone.**

```
    $data = $this->input->post();
    $objectId = $data['object_id'];
    unset($data['which_ever_field']);
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        $exp = explode("-",$key);
        $data_two = array(
            'array_key'     => $exp[0],
            'content'       => $value,
            'news_id'       => $objectId,
        );
        $this->db->insert('tbl_news_content',$data_two);                    
    }
```